# Installing Matplotlib on Mac OS X Yosemite for Python 3.2.2?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, python-3.2

For my college physics class, we are required to install Python 3.2.2 and a module called matplotlib. I have successfully installed Python 3.2.2 along with Visual Python. However, my numerous colleagues (including the professor) have tried to get matplotlib to work on with Python 3.2.2. We have tried MacPorts:

`sudo port install py32-matplotlib`

and we keep getting the error:

`Port py32-matplotlib not found.`

Some students, including me, have resorted to using Anaconda which uses python 2.7, but we would like to be able to use 3.2.2 in order to keep up with the class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no macport of matplotlib for Python 3.2:

https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=matplotlib

You should upgrade your Python interpreter to 3.3 or 3.4 and try again:

```
sudo port install py33-matplotlib
```

or

```
sudo port install py34-matplotlib
```

If you have to use Python 3.2, you can try installing it using pip:

```
sudo port install py32-pip
sudo pip-3.2 install matplotlib
```